# Meteor.js RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor server console log, I got the following error:

```
web_1  | /var/www/html/bundle/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:786
web_1  |       }).run();
web_1  |          ^
web_1  |
web_1  | RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Then Meteor server restarted itself. 
This error happens several times daily.

I searched the error in here, but couldn't find a solution.
I have a big Meteor project and I don't know where the error come from, so no code provided.

Hopefully someone know the root cause of this error, or shed some light on how to debug it.

My Meteor version is METEOR@1.4.1.3

Comment: Impossible to say without a really careful look at your code. But "Maximum call stack size exceeded" almost always means an infinite recursion. Do you have an older version of the code that worked? Just to narrow it down?

Comment: Another possibility is that you are modifying your data in reactive code that itself depends (retriggers) on that very change.

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I tried to narrow it down, but our devops could not figure out when this error came out.

Comment: Then you have a different problem! So you don't even have logs from a day when this error did *not* yet happen? You definitely need to find a way to narrow it down to a place in the code where the recursion is going berserk. So either find the time it started happening to check what changes happened, or just flood the code with log statements to see what the last line of nominal code is prior to the error.

Comment: Have you tried checking the whole project using a static linter, like `eslint`? There are some good configurations for eslint like `standard` and `prettier` and they are event capable of finding potential code smells that lead to such runtime errors.